# Javascript Thumbnail Pop ups

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

The thumbnail links on my page are working erratically when you click on them. It seems that the two links on the left and the link farthest to the right work mostly all the time but the middle links do not ever work. This is strange since I am using the same php code to build all of these links. Is it possible that I am somehow overwhelming the page with information? How would I go about fixing this problem?

http://www.robhorlacher.ca/legacyprojects.php

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="topspace"></div>
    <div id="projectContainer">
    <?php

$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'robhorla_admin';
$password = 'catinthehat4';

$connection = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
or die ('Connection error!!!');

$database = 'robhorla_legacy';
mysql_select_db($database);

    $execute_statement = "SELECT * FROM Main ORDER BY ID DESC";

    $results = mysql_query($execute_statement) or die ('Error executing SQL statement!!!');

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {

        $ID = $row["ID"];
        $datetime = $row["DateTime"];
        $tableID = $row["TID"];
        $type = $row["Type"];
        $section = $row["Section"];

    if ($type == "Websites") {

            $execute_statement2 = "SELECT * FROM Websites WHERE WID = $tableID";

            $results2 = mysql_query($execute_statement2) or die ('Error executing SQL statement2!!!');


            while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($results2)) {

            $wid = $row2["WID"];
            $wname = $row2["Name"];
            $wimage = $row2["Image"];
            $wdescription = $row2["Description"];
            $wextension = $row2["URL"];
            $wthumbnail = $row2["Thumbnail"];

            print "<div class=\"thumbnail\">";
                print "<a href=\"#yourModalId$ID\"><img src = \"uploads/$wthumbnail\" alt=\"$wname\" width=\"150\" height=\"150\">";
                print "</a></a>";
            print "</div>";
                print "<div id=\"yourModalId$ID\" class=\"yourModalClass\" style=\"display:none;\">";



                        print "<div class=\"toppop\">";
                            print "<div class=\"poptitle\">$wname</div>";
                            print "<div class=\"popclose\"><a href=\"#yourModalId$ID\"><img src=\"images/close_off.png\" alt=\"Close Popup\" width=\"45\" height=\"47\" id=\"Close Popup\"></a></div>";
                            print "<div class=\"toppopfooter\"></div>";
                        print "</div>";
            print "<div class=\"WebImage\">";
            print "<img src = \"uploads/$wimage\" width=\"auto\" height=\"auto\"></a>";
            print "</div>";
    print "<div class=\"WebDescription\">";     
    print $wdescription;
    print "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    print "<a href=\"http://$wextension\" target=\"_blank\">";
    print "Go to Website";
    print "</a>";
    print "</div>";

    print "</div>";
    print "<script src=\"js/modality.js\"></script>";
    print "<script>";
    print "var modal1 = Modality.init('#yourModalId$ID', {";
    print "    effect: 'slide-up'";
    print "});";
    print "</script>";
            }
    }

    else if ($type == "Videos") {

        $execute_statement3 = "SELECT * FROM Videos WHERE VID = $tableID";

        $results3 = mysql_query($execute_statement3) or die ('Error executing SQL statement3!!!');

                while ($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($results3)) {

                $vid = $row3["VID"];
                $vname = $row3["Name"];
                $vdescription = $row3["Description"];
                $vextension = $row3["Extension"];
                $vthumbnail = $row3["Thumbnail"];   
    print "<div class=\"thumbnail\">";
    print "<a href=\"#yourModalId$ID\"><img src = \"uploads/$vthumbnail\" alt=\"$vname\" width=\"150\" height=\"150\" border=\"0\" id=\"$vname\" />";
    print "</a></a>";
    print "</div>";

    print "<div id=\"yourModalId$ID\" class=\"yourModalClassvideo\" style=\"display:none;\">";  

            print "<div class=\"toppop\">";
                            print "<div class=\"poptitle\">$vname</div>";
                            print "<div class=\"popclose\"><a href=\"#yourModalId$ID\"><img src=\"images/close_off.png\" alt=\"Close Popup\" width=\"45\" height=\"47\" id=\"Close Popup\"></a></div>";
                            print "<div class=\"toppopfooter\"></div>";
            print "</div>";

            print "<div class=\"Video\">";
            print $vextension;
            print "</div>";
            print "<div class=\"VideoDescription\">";
            print $vdescription;
            print "</div>";


    print "</div>";
    print "<script src=\"js/modality.js\"></script>";
    print "<script>";
    print "var modal1 = Modality.init('#yourModalId$ID', {";
    print "    effect: 'slide-up'";
    print "});";
    print "</script>";
                }
    }

    else if ($type == "Images") {

    $execute_statement4 = "SELECT * FROM ImageAlbums WHERE AID = $tableID";

    $results4 = mysql_query($execute_statement4) or die ('Error executing SQL statement4!!!');

                while ($row4 = mysql_fetch_array($results4)) {

                $aid = $row4["AID"];
                $album = $row4["Name"]; 
                $athumbnail = $row4["Thumbnail"];

    print "<div class=\"thumbnail\">";
    print "<a href=\"#yourModalId$ID\"><img src = \"uploads/$athumbnail\" alt=\"$album\" width=\"auto\" height=\"auto\">";
    print "</a></a>";
    print "</div>";

    print "<div id=\"yourModalId$ID\" class=\"yourModalClassphoto\" style=\"display:none;\">";
    print "<div class=\"toppop\">";
                            print "<div class=\"poptitle\">$album</div>";
                            print "<div class=\"popclose\"><a href=\"#yourModalId$ID\"><img src=\"images/close_off.png\" alt=\"Close Popup\" width=\"45\" height=\"47\" id=\"Close Popup\"></a></div>";
                            print "<div class=\"toppopfooter\"></div>";
            print "</div>";

            print "<div class=\"Gallery\">";
            print "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
            print "$(function(){";
            print "$('.myGallery$aid').galleryView();";
            print "});";
            print "</script>";
    print "<ul class=\"myGallery$aid\">";

    $execute_statement5 = "Select * FROM Images WHERE AID = $aid";

    $results5 = mysql_query($execute_statement5) or die ('Error executing SQL statement5!!!');

                        while ($row5 = mysql_fetch_array($results5)) {

                        $extns = $row5["Extensions"];
                        print "<li><img src = \"uploads/$extns\" width=\"auto\" height=\"auto\">";
                        print "</a></li>";
                        }
    print "</ul>";                  
                        print "</div>";
                        print "</div>";
    print "<script src=\"js/modality.js\"></script>";
    print "<script>";
    print "var modal1 = Modality.init('#yourModalId$ID', {";
    print "    effect: 'slide-up'";
    print "});";
    print "</script>";
                }

            }
    }

?>
    <div id="thumbnailfooter"></div>
    </div>    
    <div id="bottomspace"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#body #content {
    width: 1080px;
    padding-bottom: 359px;
    margin: auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

#body #content #topspace {
    width: 1080px;
    height: 80px;
}

#body #content #projectContainer {
    width: 1000px;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
}

#body #content #projectContainer .thumbnail {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.modality-modal {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    visibility: hidden; 
    *zoom: 1;    
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s;
    transition: all 0.25s; 
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px; 
    -moz-perspective: 1000px; 
    perspective: 1000px; 
}
.mm-wrap {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;

    max-width: 94%;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
    z-index: 10000;
    *zoom: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
    transition: all 0.4s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.modality-modal:before, .mm-ghost {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: -0.25em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    *zoom: 1;
}

.modality-modal.mm-show .mm-wrap {
    opacity: 1;
}
body.mm-show { overflow: hidden; }

.modality-modal.mm-show {
    background: rgba(20, 194, 20, 0.5);
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 10000;
}

#body #content #projectContainer .yourModalClass {
    background-color: #000000;
    border: 6px solid #FFF;
    width: 922px;
    height: 690px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#body #content #projectContainer .yourModalClass .toppop {
    width: 922px;
    height: 47px;
}

#body #content #projectContainer .yourModalClass .toppop .poptitle {
    width: 877px;
    height: 47px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 42px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    text-indent: 24px;
}

#body #content #projectContainer .yourModalClass .toppop .popclose {
    width: 45px;
    height: 47px;   
    float: left;
}

#body #content #projectContainer .yourModalClass .toppop .toppopfooter {
    width: 922px;
    clear: both;    
}

#body #content #projectContainer .yourModalClass .WebImage {
    height: 450px;
    width: auto;
    padding-top: 34px;
    text-align: center;
}

#body #content #projectContainer .yourModalClass .WebDescription {
    width: 922px;
    height: 120px;
    padding-top: 34px;
    text-indent: 50px;
}

#body #content #projectContainer .yourModalClassvideo {
    background-color: #000000;
    border: 6px solid #FFF;
    width: 922px;
    height: 690px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#body #content #projectContainer .yourModalClassvideo .toppop {
    width: 922px;
    height: 47px;
}

#body #content #projectContainer .yourModalClassvideo .toppop .poptitle {
    width: 877px;
    height: 47px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 42px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    text-indent: 24px;
}

#body #content #projectContainer .yourModalClassvideo .toppop .popclose {
    width: 45px;
    height: 47px;   
    float: left;
}

#body #content #projectContainer .yourModalClassvideo .toppop .toppopfooter {
    width: 922px;
    clear: both;    
}

#body #content #projectContainer .yourModalClassvideo .Video {
    height: 450px;
    width: auto;
    padding-top: 34px;  
}

#body #content #projectContainer .yourModalClassvideo .Video iframe {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#body #content #projectContainer .yourModalClassvideo .VideoDescription {
    width: 922px;
    height: 120px;
    padding-top: 34px;
    text-indent: 50px;
}

#body #content #projectContainer .yourModalClassphoto {
    background-color: #000000;
    border: 6px solid #FFF;
    width: 944px;
    height: 642px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#body #content #projectContainer .yourModalClassphoto .toppop {
    width: 944px;
    height: 47px;
    text-align: left;
}

#body #content #projectContainer .yourModalClassphoto .toppop .poptitle {
    width: 899px;
    height: 47px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 42px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    text-indent: 24px;
}

#body #content #projectContainer .yourModalClassphoto .toppop .popclose {
    width: 45px;
    height: 47px;   
    float: left;
}

#body #content #projectContainer .yourModalClassphoto .toppop .toppopfooter {
    width: 944px;
    clear: both;    
}

#body #content #projectContainer .yourModalClassphoto .Gallery {
    width: 800px;
    height: 445px;
    padding-top: 61px;
    padding-left: 67px;
}

/* Effect 1 & 2: scale up and down */
.scale-up .mm-wrap {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.7);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.7);
    transform: scale(0.7);
}
.scale-down .mm-wrap {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    -moz-transform: scale(2);
    -ms-transform: scale(2);
    transform: scale(2);
}
.mm-show.scale-up .mm-wrap,
.mm-show.scale-down .mm-wrap {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}

#body #content #projectContainer #thumbnailfooter {
    width: 1080px;
    height: auto;
    clear: both;
}

#body #content #bottomspace {
    width: 1080px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
;(function () {

    var _name = "Modality", 

        _body = document.querySelector('body'),

        _defaults = {
            autoBind: true, 
            clickOffToClose: true, 
            closeOnEscape: true, 
            effect: "", 
            innerClass: "mm-wrap", 
            modalClass: "modality-modal", 
            onClose: "", 
            onOpen: "", 
            openClass: "mm-show", 
            openOnLoad: false, 
            userClass: "" 
        }, 


    _extend = function () {
        var a = arguments;
        for( var i = 1; i < a.length; i++ )
            for( var key in a[i] )
                if(a[i].hasOwnProperty(key))
                    a[0][key] = a[i][key];
        return a[0];
    },


    _addEvent = function( target, event, fn ) {
        if ( target.attachEvent ) {
            target['e'+event+fn] = fn;
            target[event+fn] = function(){ target['e'+event+fn]( window.event ); }
            target.attachEvent( 'on'+event, target[event+fn] );
        } else {
           target.addEventListener( event, fn, false );
        }
    },


    hasClass = function( target, className ) {
        return target.className.match(new RegExp('(\\s|^)'+className+'(\\s|$)'));
    },
    addClass = function( target, className ) {
        for( var i = 0; i < target.length; i++ )
            if( ! hasClass( target[i], className ) ) 
                target[i].className += " " + className;
    },
    removeClass = function( target, className ) {
        for( var i = 0; i < target.length; i++ ) {
            if( hasClass( target[i], className ) ) {
                var re = new RegExp("(\\s|^)" + className + "(\\s|$)", "g");
                target[i].className = target[i].className.replace(re , '');
            }
        }
    },

    _wrap = function ( element, settings ) {

        var container = document.createElement('div');
        container.setAttribute( 'class', settings.modalClass + ' ' + settings.effect + ' ' + settings.userClass );
        container.innerHTML = '<div class="'+settings.innerClass+'">' + element.outerHTML + '</div>';

        element.parentNode.replaceChild( container, element );

        return container;
    },



    Modality = function ( element, options ) {

        var inst = this; 


        inst.defaults = _defaults;
        inst.id       = element.getAttribute( 'id' );
        inst.settings = _extend( {}, _defaults, options );
        inst.wrapper  = _wrap( element, inst.settings );
        inst.triggers = document.querySelectorAll( 'a[href="#'+inst.id+'"], [data-modality="#'+inst.id+'"]' );
        inst.modal    = document.getElementById( inst.id );

        if( inst.settings.autoBind ) {
            for( var i = 0; i < inst.triggers.length; i++ )
                inst.setTrigger( inst.triggers[i] );
        }

        if( inst.settings.clickOffToClose ) {
    _addEvent( inst.wrapper, "click", function(e) {
        if(e.target == inst.wrapper) {
            e.preventDefault();
            inst.close();
        }
    }, false );
}

        if( inst.settings.closeOnEscape ) {
            _addEvent( _body, "keyup", function (e) {
                if(e.keyCode == 27) inst.close();
            }, false);
        }


        if( inst.modal.style.display == 'none' ) inst.modal.style.display = '';

        if( inst.settings.openOnLoad ) inst.open();


        return inst;

    };



    _extend( Modality.prototype, {

        open: function ( callback ) {

            addClass( [this.wrapper, _body], this.settings.openClass );

            if ( typeof this.settings.onOpen == 'function' ) this.settings.onOpen();
            if ( typeof callback == 'function' ) callback();

            return this;

        },

        close: function ( callback ) {


            removeClass( [this.wrapper, _body], this.settings.openClass );


            if ( typeof this.settings.onClose == 'function' ) this.settings.onClose();
            if ( typeof callback == 'function' ) callback();

            return this;

        },


        toggle: function ( callback ) {
            return ( this.isOpen() ) ? this.close(callback) : this.open(callback);
        },

        isOpen: function () {
            return hasClass( this.wrapper, this.settings.openClass );
        },


        setTrigger: function ( trigger ) {

            var inst = this; 

            _addEvent( trigger, "click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault(); inst.toggle(); 
            }, false );

            return inst;
        }

    });


    _extend( Modality, { 

        instances: {}, 
        extend: _extend, 


        init: function ( query, options ) {
            var a = {}, e = document.querySelectorAll(query);
            for( var i = 0; i < e.length; i++ ) {
                var inst = new this( e[i], options );
                this.instances[ inst.id ] = a[i] = inst;
            }
            return ( a[1] === undefined ) ? a[0] : a;
        }

    });



    window[ _name ] = Modality;


})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change something on your css:

on `.modality-modal`, add `display: none`,
and on `.modality-modal.mm-show`, add `display: block`.

On your current code, you are toggling the modal only by 'visibility' property. Note that setting `visibility : false` leaves the space taken up by that element, just like using `opacity: 0`. Toggling `display` as well solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your `.modality-modal` element. It's visible at all times and it is covering most of the links.

Just add:

```
.modality-modal {
  display: none;
}
```

and see if that helps.

I strongly recommend checking the site with the [Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) before proceeding with further development.